# When manipulating browser history with pushState/popState, backspace messes up the page transitions

Tags: jquery, html, pushstate, backspace, popstate

I am using pushstate/popstate with my ajax website, it works fine, and when i click links, i use this procedure:

```
var locked = false;

$(document.body).unbind().on('click', '.transition', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
        if (!locked) {
            locked = true;
            setTimeout(unlock, 1000);
        }
        code here...
});
```

Which works fine, but when i press backspace i have a hard time preventing the URL to change, i can use the same procedure to prevent spamming the backspace button, which will not fire my page transition, BUT it will no matter what i do, fire the url change, so it causes the history to be "out of sync" aka does not work.

I tried to use this on backspace:

```
$('html').keyup(function(e) {       
     if(e.keyCode === 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!locked) {
            locked = true;
            setTimeout(unlock, 1000);          
        }
     }
});
```

Which does prevent it from being spammed as i said, but it still changes the browser URL, and mess up everything.

tldr:
Is it possible to make backspace work properly, and prevent it from messing up my manipulated browser history since i use page transition when loading my ajax content?

Comment: Have you considered attaching a keydown event listener on the window object to preventDefault on the backspace button?

Comment: Yes, read updated answer for my code snippet :)